# Div larger than table cell

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to have a div sit in a table cell. The div is larger than the table cell and I want the table cell not to resize, but to stay the same size as the div floats over the table. How can I manipulate CSS and elements to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your `td` the css `position: relative;`

Give your `div` the css `position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;`

Here's a link to an example: http://jsfiddle.net/XLSXz/1/

Comment: @tw16 Thanks a lot for pointing that out! I forgot to hit save and just followed the habit of copying and pasting the url, but I hadn't even saved it yet, so I was just on the homepage haha. I saved it and edited my post :)

Comment: No worries, I have definitely done that before while copying a url from jsfiddle!

Comment: The fiddle was a big help. I realized I needed to set td.overflow to visible